# Put results as column names in R

Tags: r

I want to convert the result of this function:

```
> combn(1:9,6)
         [,75] [,76] [,77] [,78] [,79] [,80] [,81] [,82] [,83] [,84]
[1,]     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     3     4
[2,]     4     4     5     4     4     4     4     4     5     5
[3,]     5     6     6     5     5     5     5     6     6     6
[4,]     7     7     7     6     6     6     7     7     7     7
[5,]     8     8     8     7     7     8     8     8     8     8
[6,]     9     9     9     8     9     9     9     9     9     9
```

In a vector containing the results of every column as a "text". I'm using the "paste" function but I only can do it for a unique column:

```
 > paste(combn(1:9,6)[,84], collapse = '-')
 [1] "4-5-6-7-8-9"
```

And I want to have a vector with 84 values like this:

```
 > comb
 [1] "4-5-6-7-8-9" "3-4-5-6-7-8"....
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `FUN` argument in `combn`

```
v1 <- combn(1:9,6, FUN = paste, collapse="-")
length(v1)
#[1] 84
v1[84]
#[1] "4-5-6-7-8-9"
```